# How do I select rows where a condition is met if they exist, otherwise select all rows?

Tags: mysql

I want to select rows where `name='David'` only if they exist, If no such rows

I want to `select * rows`. There follows my statement which doesn't work:

```
SELECT * FROM table A
Where name='David'
else
SELECT * from table A
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

use below query it will work

```
  select m1.name from
   (
    select m1.*, case when m1.name ='David' then 1  else 0  end  as cnt from tableA m1 ) m1
     inner join 
    (
    select max(Cnt) as Cnt from
    (
     select t1.*, case when name ='David' then 1  else 0  end  as Cnt 
      from tableA t1
     ) as t2

     )as n 
     on m1.cnt=n.Cnt
```

http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/88ed0c/2

Comment: Thanks for your response Zaynul abadin Tuhin, your answer is working